# How can I acces c# dictionary elements from the below syntax?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, dictionary, generics

I have created a list that represents the cell values from an xls sheet and it looks something like this, followed by an INSERT statement that I will use to put the values in a certain database:

```
List<FieldValues> fieldValues = new List<FieldValues>()
{
    new FieldValues(tableFields[0]) {
        dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            {0, "" },
            {1, "" }
        }

    },
    new FieldValues(tableFields[1]) {
        dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            {0, "x" },
            {1, "x" }
        }

    },
    new FieldValues(tableFields[2]) {
        dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            {0, "x" },
            {1, "x" }
        }

    },
    new FieldValues(tableFields[3])  {
        dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            {0, "Car" },
            {1, "Travel" }
        }

    },
};


string createQuery2 = createQuery + "\n INSERT INTO `poi_specs_mgu_ece_1.6` (";

for (var i = 0; i < tableFields.Count; i++)
{
    createQuery2 += "\n\t" + tableFields[i].GetFieldDeclaration() + (i == tableFields.Count - 1 ? string.Empty : ",");
}
createQuery2 += ")\n VALUES ( ";


for (var i = 0; i < fieldValues.Count; i++)
{

    createQuery2 += "\n\t" + fieldValues[i].dictionary; //+ (i == fieldValues.Count - 1 ? string.Empty : ",");
}
createQuery2 += " \n);";
```

When I create **createQuery2** it returns (inside VALUES) the following:

> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.String]
>     System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.String]
>     System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.String]
>     System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.String]

instead of the values inside the dictionary.
Can someone please help me to better visualize the problem? Why can't I read the dictionary elements?

Comment: fieldValues[i].dictionary is a dictionary , you becomes just ToString of it, if you would use fieldValues[i].dictionary[0] you would get vaue. BUT: Your code is open for sql injections, use parameters instead of just concatenating values!

Comment: Can you explain what represents the two keys of the dictionary? Are they the name and the value of a field?

Answer (score 1):

In this part of code:

```
createQuery2 += "\n\t" + fieldValues[i].dictionary;
```

You're adding the dictionary to a string when it's an object, so it tries to make your object into a string, which just returns the type.

You need to access the dictionary values directly instead.

Like this:

```
createQuery2 += "\n\t" + fieldValues[i].dictionary[0] + fieldValues[i].dictionary[1];
```

Comment: But, lets say that I want to create a method that checks if the dictionary has a certain row? Something like this new FieldValues(tableFields[3])  {
            dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
            {
                {0, "Car" },
                {1, "Travel" }
            } How can I acces the dictionary row

Comment: Sorry, You can ignore my last comment: it was ment to be
But, lets say that I want to create a method that checks if the dictionary has a certain row? Something like this 
public string GetRowValue(int row)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
How can I acces in order to verify if my dictionary has a certain row?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you should be able to call your new `GetRowValue(int row)` method inline instead of `fieldValues[i].dictionary[row]`. That said, it sounds like there's probably a better way to do what you're trying. If you edit the question to provide more details about what you want to accomplish perhaps people can help you come up with a better solution.

Comment: The main idea is that I want to check the existence of a certain row, depending on the types that i've defined: